# Right path to import module in Sage 10

Tags: webpack, three.js, glsl, laravel-mix

Working with Sage 10 [WordPress Starter theme](https://github.com/roots/sage/). I'm trying to import GLSL files [this way](https://github.com/aitormendez/tomasgarciapiriz/blob/main/site/web/app/themes/sage/resources/scripts/frontPage.js#L6):

```
// frontPage.js
import portalVertexShader from './shaders/front-page/portal/vertex.glsl'
```

This is the file structure:

[image: This is the file structure]

But I get something like a path error in the console:

```
app.js?id=bba838275bfcabcf4aa4:37 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './shaders/front-page/portal/vertex.glsl'
    at webpackMissingModule (app.js?id=bba838275bfcabcf4aa4:37)
    at Object../resources/scripts/frontPage.js (app.js?id=bba838275bfcabcf4aa4:37)
    at __webpack_require__ ((index):304)
    at Object../resources/scripts/app.js (app.js?id=bba838275bfcabcf4aa4:13)
    at __webpack_require__ ((index):304)
    at __webpack_exec__ (app.js?id=bba838275bfcabcf4aa4:90)
    at app.js?id=bba838275bfcabcf4aa4:91
    at Function.__webpack_require__.O ((index):340)
    at app.js?id=bba838275bfcabcf4aa4:92
    at webpackJsonpCallback ((index):425)
```

I really don’t know what is happening here. How can I import this files? Thanks!

[this is the webpack.mix config](https://github.com/aitormendez/tomasgarciapiriz/blob/main/site/web/app/themes/sage/webpack.mix.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I miss to install raw-loader

```
yarn add raw-loader --dev
```